# How to assign to a subset of an R object with a name given as string

Tags: r, subset, assign

I have the name of a matrix as string and would like to assign to a column of that matrix.

```
A <- matrix(1:4,2)
v <- 10:11
name <- "A"
get(name)[,2] <- v
```

This does not work because the LHS is just a value (i.e. a vector) and has lost the meaning of "the second column of A".

```
eval(parse(text=paste0(name,'[,2]<- v')))
```

This does the job, but a lot of people discourage the use of such a structure. What is the recommended way to go about this?

**EDIT**:
Most comments on similar problems I have found discourage the use of object names that can only be passed as strings and instead promote the use of lists, i.e.

```
l <- list(A=matrix(1:4,2))
v <- 10:11
name <- "A"
l[[name]][,2] <- v
```

but this does not really answer my question.

Comment: you should make your question more clear

Comment: If you convert the matrix to dataframe, you would be able to use `assign` i.e. `A <- as.data.frame(A);  assign(name, '[[<-'(get(name), 'V2', value=v))`

Comment: If you really have to... `assign(name, {B <- get(name); B[,2] <- v; B})`

Comment: Thank you both for your solutions. Both use a intermediate assignment to solve it. I think I could adapt something of the kind to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For changing names of columns, you should work on a data.frame and not on a matrix:

```
A <- matrix(1:4,2)
v <- 10:11
name <- "A"

A <- as.data.frame(A)
v <- as.data.frame(v)
colnames(A)[2] <- name
A[,2] <- v
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I do not want to have a named column. Instead I want to avoid having to use the name in the assignment. (I.e. no "A" in the actual replacement of the column, just a reference to "name")